# how can I decide a series of 0-1 combination is stochastically distributed?

Tags: r, statistics

I have a series composed by 0 and 1, and the 0 shows up without specfic order (as far as I can tell), how can I decide if the 0 is stochastically distributed?
pls find the toy sample for reference

```
library(magrittr)
s1 <- runif(10)*10 %>% mod(10) %>% round(0) %>% `>`(5) %>% ifelse(1,0)
s2 <- c(0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0)
```

Comment: Your s1 results in all zeros.. is that correct? Also, why did you provide two sequences? What do you mean by "0 shows up without specfic order"? Are you interested in testing whether the number of zeros is similar to the ones? Or if the sequences of zeros are different than the sequences of ones?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `binom.test` ? `binom.test(sum(s2==1), length(s2))`

Answer (score 4):

The [runs test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_runs_test) is what you want:

> The Wald–Wolfowitz runs test (or simply runs test), named after
> statisticians Abraham Wald and Jacob Wolfowitz is a non-parametric
> statistical test that checks a randomness hypothesis for a two-valued
> data sequence. More precisely, it can be used to test the hypothesis
> that the elements of the sequence are mutually independent.

It is implemented in the [snpar package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/snpar/versions/1.0/topics/runs.test).

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `rbinom`? This function simulates a Bernoulli process with a chance of success (1) equal to some probability `p`. Otherwise, the result is 0.

The usage of `rbinom` is `rbinom(n, size, prob)`, where `n` is the number of random numbers to generate, `size` is the number of trials, and `prob` is the probability of getting a success. So to generate a bunch of binomial random numbers with equal probability of 1 or 0, use:

```
set.seed(100) # for reproducibility
rbinom(n = 10, size = 1, prob = 0.5) 
[1] 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
```

Comment: Thanks, Ben. But I am not looking for ways of generating 0-1 series. I am looking for a way to prove that the 0 in s1 and s2 are stochastically distributed.